# Automatically select audience for an email send

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, send-email

We are using Salesforce standard reports as audience in Marketing Cloud. The customer always use audience "A" with email "B", so i would like to know if there is a way to automatically select a certain audience, either with AMPScript or configuration, when sending an email to avoid the user to search for it inside all our folders.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be possible through the interface. 
If you are using a 'guided send' you need to select the email and then the data extension manually.

I'm not sure if this fulfills you need though - but as you say  *The customer always use audience "A" with email "B"* then my assumption is that it's the same email to the same data extension for every send, so you could create a User Initiated Send, which then you could 'save' which email is associated to which data extension. The user would then simply run the UIS ...

Documentation and guide is here :
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/

Comment: Unfortunately the User Initiated Send is not a solution for us because, even if  "The customer always use audience A with email B", they always have to do some changes to the email content

Comment: Content in the email template for UI sends is only 'frozen' once the send is scheduled. So as long as you don't schedule this send out before any changes, it will always use the most up to date version.